# how to really fix ubuntu after a botched upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have done a distribution upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. Although it finished and things are running I have some issues:

- system does not recover from suspend mode, I have to restart
- the multiscreen feature is missing, I only have 1 screen
- at startup I have some apport and gtk-root system errors, for which I can only find supressing, not fixing techniques.

When I do this I get this error

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please be advised, that many of us are experiencing that same error as you have reported.  It is not directly related to how your system is running presently, and thus, if you are satisfied otherwise that your system has returned to normal, breathe freely.  This error has been reported as related to Samba and is being addressed.  You can google that error message and see it quite easily!

Comment: thanks, I fixed that talloc notice with *sudo apt-get remove libpam-smbpass*, do you have any suggestions for the multiscreen missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had difficulties in getting Linux OS to upgrade from one release to the next.  What I usually do is backup anything special in the old version and then install the new OS level from scratch.  In general, I find this to be the cleaner and less problem-filled route (i.e. more time for me to enjoy the new OS, less fiddling around with strange issues and problems).

Comment: I agree but this is not an option or the question asked here. An upgrade should do its job without ruining everything or revert the system to the previous working state.

Comment: Unfortunately from what I have experienced realities differ from the ideal by a fair margin.